# Visualize quick sort programming algorithm using Vue.js (can't deal with Promises)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, vue.js, async-await

I'm trying to visualize quicksort algorithm using Vue.js just in self-educational purposes, and I can't deal with async/await. Filling and shuffling an array works fine (though it may be implemented wrong, I don't know.)

The sorting works oddly. I suppose that this is because of the async/await in the recursion. But I'm not a programmer actually, just know some basics so will be grateful for any help. And the code from the snippet may look ugly to you :)

```js
// noprotect

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    numArray: []
  },
  methods: {
    fillArray: function(event) {
      for (var i = 0; i<30; i++) {
        this.numArray.push(i);
      }
    },
    shuffleArray: function(event) {
      var tempArray = shuffleArray(this.numArray);
      this.numArray = tempArray;
    },
    sortArray: function(event) {
      this.numArray = quickSort(this.numArray,0,this.numArray.length-1)
      console.log(this.numArray);
    }
  }
})
Vue.config.devtools = false;

function sleep(ms = 0) {
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));
};

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function shuffleArray(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length,
      temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    Vue.set(array,currentIndex,array[randomIndex]);
    Vue.set(array,randomIndex,temporaryValue);
  }

  return array;
}


function quickSort(arr, left, right) {
  var len = arr.length,
      pivot,
      partitionIndex;


  if (left < right) {
    pivot = right;
    partitionIndex = partition(arr, pivot, left, right);

    quickSort(arr, left, partitionIndex - 1);
    quickSort(arr, partitionIndex + 1, right);
  }
  return arr;
}

async function partition(arr, pivot, left, right) {
  var pivotValue = arr[pivot],
      partitionIndex = left;

  for (var i = left; i < right; i++) {
    if (arr[i] < pivotValue) {
      swap(arr, i, partitionIndex);
      await sleep(100);
      partitionIndex++;
    }
  }
  swap(arr, right, partitionIndex);
  await sleep(100);
  return partitionIndex;
}

function swap(arr, i, j) {
  var temporaryValue = arr[i];
  
  Vue.set(arr,i,arr[j]);
  Vue.set(arr,j,temporaryValue);
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.el {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  float: left;
  width: 2%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 25px;
  margin: 0 2px;
}


.btn {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  clear: both;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="container" id="scene1">
      <div class="el" v-for="item in numArray">{{ item }}</div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" v-on:click.prevent="fillArray" class="btn">Fill array</a>
    <a href="#" v-on:click.prevent="shuffleArray" class="btn">Shuffle array</a>
    <a href="#" v-on:click.prevent="sortArray" class="btn">Sort array</a>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't have much expertise in async/await, but I think your `quicksort` function needs to be `async` because it relies on `partition` (which is `async`). I think the call to `partition` should have an `await`.

Answer (score 0):

The `async` `partition` function does return a promise, not an integer. You need to wait for it, making `quicksort` asynchronous as well.

```
async function quickSort(arr, left, right) {
  const len = arr.length;

  if (left < right) {
    const pivot = right;
    const partitionIndex = await partition(arr, pivot, left, right);

    await quickSort(arr, left, partitionIndex - 1);
    await quickSort(arr, partitionIndex + 1, right);
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Same then for the app's `sortArray` method.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```js
function quickSortPromise(arr) {
 return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) =>{
  if (arr.length < 2) resolve(arr)
  else {
   let [pivot, ...arr1] = arr;
   let right = [], left = []
   for (let i of arr1) {
    if (i < pivot) left.push(i)
    else right.push(i)
   }
   let sortArr = await Promise.all([quickSortPromise(left),quickSortPromise(right)])
   // console.log(`pivot: ${pivot}, sortArr: ${sortArr}`)
   resolve([...sortArr[0], pivot, ...sortArr[1]])
 }
})
}
```

Comment: Some explanation would greatly improve the quality of the answer and help other users who may encounter similar problems in the future
Please take some time to read the help page https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer